# Why keyboard doesn’t show all the languages?

Tags: ios

When I test my app in my iPhone, from the pictures, you can see I only have two languages available, but I have all the languages from any other app.

The textfield in my app uses the default configuration.

It happens only in a few devices, I have no idea what happened here, does anyone know the reason?

[image: keyboard in my app]

[image: Keyboard in other app]

Comment: The user specifies in the Settings app which languages should be shown in the keyboard, so this is controlled by the user, and your app cannot change it. (Settings -> General -> Keyboard -> Keyboards -> Add New Keyboard.)

Comment: @gnasher729 thanks, the user have all the languages when he opens other app, only my app displays two languages.